Why isn't my @IBAction function for my UIButton being registered by the program?
I am creating a survey as a part of the app that I'm building. It should be so that if one of the multiple choice options is selected and the Next button is tapped, then the data from that answer is updated to Firebase Firestore. However, right now, the code just does nothing. Not even the test statement is printed, which makes me wonder if something about the view controller itself has an error.
I tried to create just a blank button with only a print statement inside this view controller, but even then, nothing is printed. Also, I checked to make sure my Next button is connected to the code as well as the spelling for the different functions and segues. However, despite deleting the button and reconnecting it to the code, nothing is happening. I also cleared my build folder.
Currently, if I click the Next button, the code does nothing. Not even the test statement print("button pressed method accessed") is printed even if isBtnSelected is true.
Here is my code for the @IBAction:
@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if isbtnSelected == true {
            print("button pressed method accessed")
            UserData.shared.years = Int((self.currentButton.titleLabel?.text)!)!
            
            if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                let userPreferencesCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("user_preferences")
                let userDocumentRef = userPreferencesCollectionRef.document(user.uid)
                
                var questionData: [String: Any] = [:]
                questionData["years"] = UserData.shared.years

                userDocumentRef.setData(questionData, merge: true) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error setting preferences: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Preferences set successfully!")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextQues", sender: self)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please select an answer", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Okay", comment: "Close alert"), style: .default))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
    }

Here is a screenshot of the Interface Builder for the Next Button:
Screenshot
After creating multiple breakpoints at different locations, I found that there is an error that prevents the performSegue to be implemented. However, my Debug area has nothing printed, so I can't figure out where the error is coming from. Here is a screenshot of the breakpoint message:
Breakpoint message

The key part is how you connect the IBAction to the button. you need to go into Interface Builder and control-drag from the action of the button to the IBAction. Post a screenshot of the Interface Builder connection. (alternatively you can make the target/action in code by using the method addTarget(_:action:for:). That is easier to show in a Stack Overflow post.)

@Duncan Thanks for the suggestion! I just edited my post to include the screenshot of Interface Builder, and I also did the control-drag action. However, it still doesn't seem to be working.

The other key part is how you create the view controller instance.  If you don't create it from the storyboard, actions and views aren't connected.  How are you creating the view controller?

@Paulw11 Thanks for the comment! Yes, I created the view controller from storyboard.

Set a breakpoint on the if isbtnSelected selected line - It seems likely that that is false.

If you have IBOutlet in that ViewController, could you try in viewDidLoad() to print them? There no view above that one that might block the touch? If you use Debug View Hierarchy just before clicking on the button, there is nothing blocking the touch?

@Paulw11 I just set a breakpoint there, but it appears to be true. Everything seems to be running up until the if let error = error part. I just attached a screenshot of it to my post.

@Larme Thanks! I just checked my Debug View Hierarchy, but there isn't anything blocking the touch.

Great that you solved it.  Learn to use the Xcode debugger.  It is much more powerful than sprinkling print statements everywhere.

There were several issues that I overlooked:

I was looking at the Variables console instead of the actual console, which meant that I couldn't see any of the print messages.

The actual problem wasn't with my code or the way I set things up in Xcode, but it was with my Firestore Rules section. Before, I didn't let the users read or write their preferences, but after switching it to the following code, everything ran smoothly.
Firestore Rules Code


Sorry for any confusion due to the misleading question!

It's great that you solved it, but this answer in no way emerges from the nature of the question or the information in the question, so this is not a good answer to the question as asked. It might be better just to delete the question itself.
